# Webscraping Dynamic Webpage w/ load button

Tags: javascript, selenium, button, web-scraping, scroll

I am trying to webscrape US News (https://www.usnews.com/best-colleges/rankings/national-universities?_mode=table'). There is a 'Load More' button which dynamically loads the table. There are 388 schools and 10 are loaded each time. Factoring in the original 10 that are showed upon the initial load of the page, I should click the load more button 37 times.

The way the webapge works is that when the user scrolls so that the 'Load More' button is in view, then the loading of the next set automatically triggers (but sometimes it doesn't and you have to physcially click the button.

So, I set up a selenium webdriver and I have a scrollMore() function that 1) finds the button in HTML, scrolls the button into view, and then clicks it. I'm also clearing cookies in between, otherwise I'm blocked by their server. I initially used selenium functions to do this separately, but I think there must have been some race conditions because I would get a time out when trying to find the button after some iterations.

So, I'm trying to do it synchronously and this is what I currently have:

```
self.driver.execute_script("var button = document.evaluate(\"//button[normalize-space()='Load More']\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;"\
                           "button.scrollIntoView();"\
                           "button.disabled = false; button.click();")
```

The problem is that it works for exactly 19 loads, but no matter what I try, I cannot get the 20th load. What is a possible suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable browser notifications for selenium driver, looks like at some point some are initiated and prevent further interaction with page elements.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. These are the options I am passing the chromedriver options = ['user-agent='+userAgent,'--headless','--disable-notifications','disable-popup-blocking', '--no-sandbox','disable-dev-shm-usage']